# what differs 2 function calls in a row?

Tags: windows, stack, cpu-registers

Suppose you look at the stack and registers of a process which has the following code...

```
...
void Test()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
          OneRunDontKnow();
     }
}
...
```

You look at the stack twice exactly when the process executes the loop, and in both times the `OneRunDontKnow` is at the top of the stack.

Can you somehow know if `OneRunDontKnow` was popped out of the stack and then pushed in again or if it was never popped out?

EDIT: `OneRunDontKnow` can have any signature (it can also take parameters or return a value).

Comment: by examining the stack pointer? However, nowadays' compilers do a lot of tricks, namely inlining.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: the problem is that local variables are created on the stack as well.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to look at your assembled code.  `OneRunDontKnow()` takes no parameters, so the only thing on the stack will be the instruction pointer, and other stack frame stuff, but no parameters. So find the place in the disassembly where `OneRunDontKnow()` should be called, and see what kind of `PUSH` and `JMP` inside the code where `LOOP_` (`LOOP`, `LOOPE`, etc) is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand what you meant.
('OneRunDontKnow' CAN take parameters, It can have any signature)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought in your particular case it didn't. If it does, it should be easier to see the stack frame, as more things will get `PUSH`ed onto the stack.

Comment: can you please elaborate on that?